# An error occurred (UnauthorizedOperation) when calling the DescribeLaunchTemplates operation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible, amazon-iam, aws-auto-scaling

I was trying to deploy launch template in my AWS autoscaling group using ansible!
Here was my script

```
- name: base64 conversion
  command: base64 -w 0 roles/inspect/tasks/user_data_cs.sh 
  register: userdata

- debug:
    var: userdata.stdout

#To deploy the user data in lauch template
- name: User data deployment
  ec2_launch_template:
    name: "{{ LT_name }}" 
    image_id: "ami-##########" 
    key_name: "aws-dev"
    block_device_mappings:
     - device_name: "/dev/sdb"
       ebs:
         volume_size: 20
         encrypted: true
     - device_name: "/dev/xvda"
       ebs:
         volume_size: 10
         volume_type: gp2
         delete_on_termination: yes
         encrypted: true
    default_version: 1
    ebs_optimized: no
    iam_instance_profile: "aws-ec2-role"
    network_interfaces:
    - device_index : 0
      delete_on_termination: yes
      associate_public_ip_address: no
      groups: ["sg-##########"]
    instance_type: t3.small
    user_data: "{{ userdata.stdout }}"
  when: name_env == "dev"
```

It was showing error

`TASK [inspect : User data deployment] ****************************************** An exception occurred during task execution. To see the full traceback, use -vvv. The error was: botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (UnauthorizedOperation) when calling the DescribeLaunchTemplates operation: You are not authorized to perform this operation. [WARNING]: The value 1 (type int) in a string field was converted to '1' (type string). If this does not look like what you expect, quote the entire value to ensure it does not change. fatal: [127.0.0.1]: FAILED! => {"boto3_version": "1.24.38", "botocore_version": "1.27.38", "changed": false, "error": {"code": "UnauthorizedOperation", "message": "You are not authorized to perform this operation."}, "msg": "Could not check existing launch templates. This may be an IAM permission problem.: An error occurred (UnauthorizedOperation) when calling the DescribeLaunchTemplates operation: You are not authorized to perform this operation.", "response_metadata": {"http_headers": {"cache-control": "no-cache, no-store", "content-type": "text/xml;charset=UTF-8", "date": "Thu, 05 Jan 2023 13:17:02 GMT", "server": "AmazonEC2", "strict-transport-security": "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains", "transfer-encoding": "chunked", "vary": "accept-encoding", "x-amzn-requestid": "c0cd0411-c88e-4569-bd91-21dd46708224"}, "http_status_code": 403, "request_id": "c0cd0411-c88e-4569-bd91-21dd46708224", "retry_attempts": 0}}`

Here was my IAM permssions!
There seems to be no action as "DescribeLaunchTemplate"
I tried with autoscaling:DescribeLaunchTemplate elasticloadbalancing:DescribeLaunchTemplate
application-autoscaling:DescribeLaunchTemplate
also only
DescribeLaunchTemplate

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "elasticloadbalancing:DescribeLoadBalancers",
                "autoscaling:UpdateAutoScalingGroup",
                "autoscaling:CreateOrUpdateTags"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

and

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "application-autoscaling:RegisterScalableTarget",
                "application-autoscaling:DeleteScheduledAction",
                "application-autoscaling:DescribeScalableTargets",
                "application-autoscaling:DeleteScalingPolicy",
                "elasticloadbalancing:DescribeLoadBalancers",
                "autoscaling:DescribeAutoScalingGroups",
                "application-autoscaling:DescribeScalingActivities",
                "application-autoscaling:DescribeScalingPolicies",
                "application-autoscaling:PutScalingPolicy",
                "elasticloadbalancing:DescribeTargetGroups",
                "autoscaling:DescribeLoadBalancerTargetGroups",
                "application-autoscaling:DescribeScheduledActions",
                "application-autoscaling:PutScheduledAction",
                "application-autoscaling:DeregisterScalableTarget"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

I also tried adding "DescribeLaunchTemplates" but there seems to be no action on IAM like that checked with asg and everything.

Answer (score 1):

Adding

```
"ec2:DescribeLaunchTemplates",
"ec2:DescribeLaunchTemplateVersions"
```

Resolved this issue